# Fancybox Pop Up Warning for IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, fancybox

I am trying to create a fancybox/lightbox warning that will display when a user visit my site using IE7. I was digging around on the Fancybox website and I came across this script that will allow the fancybox to display on the page launch. The I added an IE7 if statement to the mix. So my final code was something similar to the one below:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$.fancybox(
    '<h2>Hi!</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis mi eu elit tempor facilisis id et neque</p>',
    {
            'autoDimensions'    : false,
        'width'                 : 350,
        'height'                : 'auto',
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none'
    }
);
});
<![endif]-->
```

In short it didnt work. I put the code right after my body and also just to be clear I did have all of the js files and jquery files enabled in my head. Any ideas on how I can get this to work? Is there a better solution out there for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$.fancybox(
    '<h2>Hi!</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis mi eu elit tempor facilisis id et neque</p>',
    {
            'autoDimensions'    : false,
        'width'                 : 350,
        'height'                : 'auto',
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none'
    }
);
});
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

You need the `<script>` tag.

You could use a browser sniffing script instead of conditional commenting...

Something like:

```
if($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) < 8){ // This would catch IE7 and below
    //fancybox script   
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add that in the post. When I tested it I did have them in. When the page would load it would just load a blank page.

Comment: Do you have any browser sniffing scripts that you would recommend? I have broken this down into an if statement that will display the message if the browser version is less than 8. Problem I am having now is finding a simple enough script that will give me the browser version number. I have looked at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/ but I cant figure out whats going on. From there I could export the javascript variable into a PHP variable. Problem is I am not sure on how to do that. Any ideas on how that can be done?